# Doctrine - "Missing value for primary key"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with an invalid mapping. I keep getting an error with message:

> Missing value for primary key course on "Namespace\XXX\Entity\Subject"

The doctrine:schema:validate command returns the following:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Namespace\XXX\Entity\Subject' mapping is invalid:
>   * The join columns of the association 'schedule' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'Namespace\XXX\Entity\Subject', however 'id, course, class, day, timeslot' are missing.

This is my mapping:

### Subject-entity

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oggi\ScheduleBundle\Entity\Schedule", inversedBy="subjects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schedule", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $schedule;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;
```

### Schedule Entity

/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Oggi\KlasBundle\Entity\Course")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $course;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oggi\KlasBundle\Entity\Klas", inversedBy="schedules")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $klas;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Day")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="day", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $day;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Timeslot")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="timeslot", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $timeslot;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Oggi\CalendarBundle\Entity\Subject", mappedBy="schedule")
 */
private $subjects;
```

I suppose that what Symfony is telling me to do is include all primary keys in my subject-entity. Is there a way to only include the ID of the schedule in this entity. I had this in mind:

[image: db model]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because all columns in your `Schedule` entity are marked as an `Id`.

Just remove `@ORM\Id` from all columns but `$id` - this should fix the case

Comment: same thing happened to me and I fixed by removing @ORM\Id as in your answer. Can you explain whats going on here. I generated my entity classes from database. Is it because Doctrine is adding new id declaration other than mapping relation (in my case it was one-to-one mapping)? after that doctrine:schema:validate says mapping is ok but database schema is not in sync with the current mapping files.