# Link Doctrine Entity when I already have a dataBase

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working with an existing dataBase (from my company) and they want to build an intranet with **symfony 4**.

I created my doctrine files and the doctrine database.

And after that i used some insert command for work with all the data from the existing dataBase in the doctrine database and in my symfony project.

**For the moment everything work very well !**

But I want to add a relationship mapping (one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many) in my doctrine model now.

And in all the exemple that i found they link the model with each other inside fixture or with some new data to insert in dataBase

So I added a One-To-One unidirectionnal relationship in my Bodyshops.orm.yml link to the BodyshopsEmail.orm.yml and after used the

> doctrine:schema:update --force

With success, I want to use my Bodyshops Model in a Controller and I got a

> **Missing value for primary key senderEmail on App\Entity\BodyshopsEmail**

I know that the question was put

> [Missing value for primary key id Doctrine Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581176/missing-value-for-primary-key-id-doctrine-symfony2)
>
> [Doctrine - "Missing value for primary key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163053/doctrine-missing-value-for-primary-key)

But I guess that the error is here because I got two ID in my bodyshopsEmail id(same as bodyshops.id) and senderMail(Set foreach row in bodyshopsEmail)

**I want to know if i have to make a script that will bind my actual data relationship mapping for avoid the error or if the error doesn't come from the linking but from the orm.yml for exemple**

Hope that I am clear enough , thank's for reading :p my files are below

(EN)

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

(FR)

https://www.jdecool.fr/blog/2017/09/20/tutorial-jobeet-symfony-4-partie-3a-le-modele-de-donnees.html

[https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/les-relations-entre-entites-avec-doctrine2#*=*](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/les-relations-entre-entites-avec-doctrine2#_=_)

**Bodyshops.orm.yml**

```
App\Entity\Bodyshops:
    type: entity

    id:
        id: #B
            type: string
            length: 2

    fields:

        accessFrom:
            type: string
            length: 5
            nullable: false

        region:
            type: string
            length: 8
            nullable: false

        name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
        nameAlternative:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
        nameCode:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false

        phone:
            type: string
            length: 16
            nullable: true
        fax:
            type: string
            length: 16
            nullable: true

        website:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true

        address1:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false
        address2:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true
        address3:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true
        zip:
            type: string
            length: 6
            nullable: false
        city:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
        country:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
        countryCode:
            type: string
            length: 4
            nullable: false

        colorBackground:
            type: string
            length: 8
            nullable: false
        colorText:
            type: string
            length: 8
            nullable: true
        workshopSlots:
            type: integer
            length: 4
            nullable: false

        departements:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false

        ipList:
            type: json_array
            nullable: true

        identRepa:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true
        statutJurid:
            type: string
            length: 2
            nullable: true
        capital:
            type: string
            length: 16
            nullable: true
        natInscript:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true
        rcsRdm:
            type: string
            length: 10
            nullable: true
        gerant:
            type: string
            length: 1
            nullable: true
        codeApe:
            type: string
            length: 4
            nullable: true
        idIntracomm:
            type: string
            length: 13
            nullable: true
    oneToOne:
        email:
            targetEntity: BodyshopsEmail
            joinColumn:
                name: id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

**BodyshopsEmail.orm.yml**

```
App\Entity\BodyshopsEmail:
    type: entity

    id:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 2
            nullable: false

        senderEmail:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

    fields:
        senderName:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

        replyTo:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true


        smtpHost:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false

        smtpPort:
            type: string
            length: 6
            nullable: false

        smtpLogin:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

        smtpAuth:
            type: string
            length: 32 
            nullable: false

        smtpSecurity:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true


        popHost:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true

        popPort:
            type: string
            length: 6
            nullable: true

        imapHost:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false

        imapPort:
            type: string
            length: 6
            nullable: false


        receiveLogin:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

        receiveAuth:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false

        receiveSecurity:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false


        globalPassword:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false


        signatureFile:
            type: string
            length: 256
            nullable: true
```

I don't think that's usefull to show you the model, but be sure that every value as a getter and setter (even the $email define by the one-to-one)

Comment: What do you mean by `a script that will bind my actual data relationship mapping `?

Comment: A script that will set the new relation in each model

Answer (score 1):

You would have no schema changes if you use column already present in your database and model.

For example if you have a table `cart` with a column `customer_id` in your existing database

You could do

```
/**
 * One Cart has One Customer.
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="cart")
 * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $customer;
```

You can check using `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see if there is any sql request needed to do the changes

Comment: I fall in the same problem as them like that but all the solution are not working (I didn't remove the dataBase like in the first solution cause is exactly what i don't want)
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303062/symfony2-doctrine-schema-update-fails

Comment: I used "set foreign_key_checks=0;" and it didn't work so i used "set GLOBAL foreign_key_checks=0;" and i was able to update my db::schema. But when I try to use the entity link to my one-to-one unidirectional relation ATable->BTable it say me "Missing value for primary key BMember on BModel " (My one-to-one join A.id with B.id where id is really write 'id' it's maybe the problem ?) And my B table have two idKey one is id the other one the bMember in the error message